# Creating a dynamic pivot table query mysql with count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, report, pivot

I am trying to take a result set like this:

```
chartday    username    [number of results]
2014-12-12  person3 73
2014-12-12  person2 9
2014-12-12  person4 166
2014-12-12  person1 103
2014-12-12  person5 1
2014-12-12  person6 168

2014-12-13  person2 15
2014-12-13  person7 22
2014-12-13  person1 119
```

I would like to have the result look like this:

```
chartday   person1 person2 person3 person4 person5 person6 person7
2014-12-12 103     9       73      166     1       168     0
2014-12-13 119     15      0       0       0       0       22
```

I am using mySQL and have been working on this for a while and would like some ideas.  Here is an example I have been working with: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a068/6), but I cannot figure out how to add count(*) to return the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT chartday
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN username = 'person1' THEN CT ELSE 0 END) AS Person1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN username = 'person2' THEN CT ELSE 0 END) AS Person2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN username = 'person3' THEN CT ELSE 0 END) AS Person3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN username = 'person4' THEN CT ELSE 0 END) AS Person4
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN username = 'person5' THEN CT ELSE 0 END) AS Person5
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN username = 'person6' THEN CT ELSE 0 END) AS Person6
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN username = 'person7' THEN CT ELSE 0 END) AS Person7
FROM Table1
GROUP BY chartday
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff81be/2/0)

To make this dynamic you'd have to use prepared statements:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(username = ''',
      username,
      ''', ct, 0)) AS ',
      username
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Table1;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT chartday, ', @sql, ' FROM Table1 GROUP BY chartday');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff81be/7/5)

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is my last resort.  I'd like to leave it to where it is dynamic.  This is going to be part of a highcharts chart, and if we pull a report for for example 2014-12-13 it will only have results for person 2, 7 and 1.  And in the future when we add personnel I'd to not like to update this query everytime.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect I have arrived at my answer with your insights.  I appreciate the help!